# When casting void * to int, the address is passed, not the value

Tags: c

I have a `struct t_args` with `void*` types

```
typedef struct  s_args
{
    void    *width;
}   t_args;
```

I am passing in `void *` an `int` address. Next, we look at the value of `t_args->width` in the same function `int *q = (int *)args->width;`, it is 4, everything is correct. But as soon as I pass the struct to the "processing" function `processing(args, arg, return_len);` , then `t_args->width` turns into a huge number, as if it translates a hex address into int and writes it into int. In that case, why the first time I check the value of `t_args->width`, it displays everything correctly?

this is the function where everything works

```
void        work_with_one_argument(int *i, char *str, va_list *arg, int *return_len)
{
    t_args *args;

    *i += 1;
    if (str[*i] == '%')
    {
        ft_putchar(str[*i]);
        *i += 1;
        *return_len += 1;
    }
    create_struct(&args, i, str);
    replace_star(args, arg);
    int *q = (int *)args->width;
    processing(args, arg, return_len);
}
```

this is a function where `t` becomes trash

```
void            processing(t_args *args, va_list *arg, int *return_len)
{
    char *types;

    types = "diucpsxXnfge";
    int *t = (int *)args->width;
    if (!ft_memcmp(args->type, (void *)&types[0], 1) || \
            !ft_memcmp(args->type, (void *)&types[1], 1) || \
            !ft_memcmp(args->type, (void *)&types[2], 1))
        select_handler_int_unsign(args, arg, return_len, types);
```

this function which create struct

```
/*
**      Function:         t_args        create_struct()
**
**      Description:      function create and fill struct t_args
*/

void            create_struct(t_args **args, int *i, char *str)
{
    *args = (t_args *)malloc(sizeof(t_args));
    struct_initialization(args);
    parse_specificators(args, i, str);
}
```

this is fill args->width

```
/*
**      Function:         void      parse_spec_width()
**
**      Description:      parse width from string
*/

void            parse_spec_width(t_args **args, int *i, char *str)
{
    t_args  *tmp;
    char    *star;
    int     width;

    tmp = *args;
    star = "*";
    if (str[*i] == *star)
    {
        tmp->width = (void *)&star[0];
        *i += 1;
        return ;
    }
    if (str[*i] >= '0' && str[*i] <= '9')
    {
        width = ft_atoi(&str[*i]);
        tmp->width = (void *)&width;
        while (str[*i] >= '0' && str[*i] <= '9')
            *i += 1;
    }
}
```

I'm writing an implementation of printf. The string "%05d" is received, the width Specifier is stored in void *

Comment: Please show the code as a complete program that illustrates the problem. That is, provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please create a _complete_ program, at best including a short `main()` and including all relevant `#include`s. Please show `replace_star` and `create_struct` functions. Where is `args` initialized? Where is `args->width` initialized? Where does it point to? How is this function called?

Comment: This really smells like a dangling pointer problem. What does `args->with` point at, and what happened to that `int`?

Comment: Please indicate at what line of the code the value is correct, and at what value it isn't. BTW calling `malloc` in an implementation of `printf` might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

`replace_star(args, arg)` function incorrect.
It probably gets integer pointer from va_arg instead of integer itself. If you want to get pointer you should `malloc()` some memory and store that int.

Please, give me link so I can prove it to you.